# Snap Store does not start on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: snap-store

For a few days I have verified that SNAP STORE does not start. I normally install via terminal.

I saw a person on twitter commenting on the error, and I checked it out on my install.

When trying to run Snap Store via terminal I get the error message:

“Segmentation fault ( core dumped)”
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfPvg.png)

Comment: Try removing and reinstalling the snap-store.  `sudo snap remove snap-store` then `sudo snap install snap-store`

Comment: I do that every day, to see if it has been corrected...
I read a lot of people on Twitter with the same problem.

Comment: File it as a bug so that the developers can have a look at it.  Also, please be as detailed as possible in your questions with all the steps you have tried as well so that we are not guessing like I did above.  Thank you!

Comment: I got into exactly the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04.5 on two different machines, checked both X11 and Wayland, and I cannot remember I did something special except everyday stuff

Comment: As I have discussed with other people, the error appeared after a system update. Even if you reinstall with sudo snap remove snap-store and sudo snap install snap-store, it doesn't start. This youtuber made a video denouncing the problem, although it is in Spanish: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BR7XfOrFgU

Comment: There are bugs filed about this.  Some are saying that they are getting it in Wayland and not X11.  You should put in your info as well.  Bugs need to be handled by the developers.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store-desktop/+bug/1867679  and https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-store-segmentation-fault-in-wayland-session/16153/4

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this bug was introduced with latest GNOME language packages update. (https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store-desktop/+bug/1988440 and https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-store-is-not-starting/31536)

snap-store from the "edge" works on both 20.04 and 22.04.

This switches update channel to "edge".

```
snap refresh snap-store --edge
```

When the bug will be fixed in "stable" channel, switch back.

```
snap refresh snap-store --stable
```

Comment: Correct! changing the system language to english/eeuu, the snap store opens correctly

Comment: This answer should be accepted!

Comment: The fix for the `snap-store` has been released for "stable" for 22.04 and 22.10 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store-desktop/+bug/1988440/comments/9