# Error: Package software center has no installation candidate after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: software-center, 22.04

I upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS and now my Ubuntu Software GUI is not working anymore it is not opening at all. I have googled the entire internet and nothing works. I removed and installed gnome-software. When I tried `sudo apt install --reinstall software-center` it gave me the error: `package software center has no installation candidate`. What does that even mean? What can I do to use my Software Center again?

EDIT:

The command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` outputs the following:

```
jan@Ubuntu-20-04:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
# deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable # uitgeschakeld bij opwaardering naar jammy
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
```

SECOND EDIT:

```
jan@Ubuntu-20-04:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] wachtwoord voor jan: 
Geraakt:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                              
Ophalen:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                                                              
Geraakt:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                 
Geraakt:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                               
Geraakt:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
110 kB opgehaald in 2s (54,3 kB/s)                        
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd... Klaar
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar 
Alle pakketten zijn up-to-date.
```

Comment: Enter the command `sudo apt update` and try again. If it does not work, edit the question and post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Thank you @Archisman Panigrahi for taking the time. I edited my question as you suggested.

Comment: Can you also post the output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: Edited with `sudo apt update` output: `All packages are up-to-date`

Comment: I found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426943/snap-store-does-not-start-on-ubuntu-22-04-1#answers-header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `software-center` deb package was removed from Ubuntu before 18.04. It's been gone from the repositories a long time.

If you upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 to 20.04, the old deb package might have remained upon your system. It would still have worked.

The 'Ubuntu Software' application is currently provided by the `snap-store` snap.

`sudo snap install snap-store`

Comment: When I enter the command `sudo snap install snap-store` I get `snap "snap-store" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'`. So apparently I already have it. Now how do I get Ubuntu Software to work?

Comment: That's an entirely different question. Try the 'Search' box -- it has been asked before. This question is about the missing `software-center` deb.

Comment: Indeed, I found the answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426943/snap-store-does-not-start-on-ubuntu-22-04-1#answers-header

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure , but You can install gnome-software

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```