# Ubuntu 22.04 login loop after installing Python3.10

Tags: 22.04

Yesterday I have **installed Python 3.10** and today I’ve tried to login and I have stuck in the **login loop**. I’ve tried every suggestion on Reddit and ask ubuntu, but nothing seems to work.
I’m so demoralized.

### Edit:

Also when i enter terminal I always need to provide PATH to basic commands like (ls, sudo, etc.) after rebooting.

I’ve tried to reinstall python i’ve tried to install software-center, i got this issue [Error: Package software center has no installation candidate after upgrade to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427506/error-package-software-center-has-no-installation-candidate-after-upgrade-to-22)
After this, when i’ve rebooted and tried to login i got this:

```
[8.890130] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could 
not resolue synbol (_IZ.EIDI, 
AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)

[8.890265] ACPI Error: Aborting nethod '
SB. IEM. _OSC due to previous error 
(AF_NOT _FOUND) (20220331/psparse 529)
```

[login error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGsgA.jpg)

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 comes with Python 3.10 as default. Please tell us the exact steps you did to install another version (in your question). Note: Messing with the default Python version on Ubuntu is an experiment that usually don't ends well.

Comment: @ArturMeinild i think i’ve done something like $ echo export PATH="<PATH_TO_PYTHON>:$PATH" >> ~/.profile. 
 From here
https://realpython.com/add-python-to-path/.  
And sudo make altinstall After i’ve followed https://youtu.be/7H-DcdSmV0U.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python3.10 is available for Ubuntu 22.04 from the default repositories, you do not need to download it.

Furthermore, the system default Python version is Python3.10 and using a downloaded version to replace the default will break the system because much of the system depends on the particular default version.

Therefore, you should:

- Boot into recovery mode from your Grub menu
- select the option to drop to a root shell
- run the following command:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

- navigate to your user's home directory:

```
cd /home/PurpleAnteater
```

where `PurpleAnteater` is the actual username of your Ubuntu user (replace this with the actual username).

- Finally, edit your `.profile` file:

```
nano .profile
```

and delete the path to python from the `export PATH=` line **OR it would probably be better just to delete this line altogether**. This is most likely the last line of the file.

After the line is deleted, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the file and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Use the command:

```
reboot
```

to reboot and then you should be able to log in successfully.

Comment: If you want to install an alternative version of Python or Python3.10, you should not have the manually installed version in your PATH if the manually installed version is called by the same name, e.g., `python3.10` If you need to call the manually installed version, either create an alias for it or call it using the full path to the alternative `python3.10` command. This way, the system will still use the default version where needed but you can use your alternate version for personal use.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that we almost never need to download software for Ubuntu because almost everything is available through the default repositories using `apt`. If you want to search for available software packages, run the command `apt-cache search` followed by the package name. Example: `apt-cache search python3.10` This will list all available and related packages. To install a package for example, just run something like `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install python3.10`.

Comment: To find out more information about a package like the version number, you can run this for example: `apt-cache show python3.10` . Finally, to filter your results, you can pipe the results to `grep` like in this command to only display results that contain the word "python": `apt-cache search python3.10 | grep -i python` And the `-i` option here disables case sensitivity for your matches.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! Just followed your steps and it worked (deleted entire row in .profile)